# Power BI - DAX - ADDCOLUMNS - Syntax Error - Invalid token, Line 3, Offset 2,

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is from the Coursera Power BI course.  I'm trying to create a create a "Sales in USD" calculated table.  I was instructed to select a New Table in Power BI and type the following:

```
Sales in USD =  
     ADDCOLUMNS(
        Sales,
        "Country Name", RELATED(Countries[Country]),
        "Exchange Rate", RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
        "Exchange Currency", RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Currency]),
        "Gross Revenue USD", [Gross Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
        "Net Revenue USD", [Net Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
        "Total Tax USD", [Total Tax] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate])
    )
```

It generated "The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 3, Offset 2,  ."

I've looked online for how the ADDCOLUMNS function is used, and the code above seemed to comport with the explanations that I read online.

What am I - I mean Coursera - doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some of the quotes and apostrophes may be "dirty" or there are some invisible whitespace characters. This happens sometimes when copying/pasting code from websites.

Try copying/pasting the below or from your question.

```
Sales in USD =  
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    Sales,
    "Country Name", RELATED(Countries[Country]),
    "Exchange Rate", RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
    "Exchange Currency", RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Currency]),
    "Gross Revenue USD", [Gross Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
    "Net Revenue USD", [Net Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate]),
    "Total Tax USD", [Total Tax] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Rate])
  )
```

If that doesn't work, then please update your question with a screen grab of your expression in Power BI. The wavy red-underlines should hopefully help identity the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get this same script in the Coursera's final project to work too and it won't.  This isn't the first time the code or files I downloaded for this course don't work, but in the second half of this project they make us create measures based on this table, so it's hard to skip around this.

I got mine to work.  You need to fix the squiggly red lines because the syntax for the tables aren't named right.  Look at mine:

```
Sales in USD = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    Sales,
    "Country Name", RELATED(Countries[Country]),
    "Exchange Rate", RELATED('Exchange Data'[ExchangeRate]),
    "Exchange Currency", RELATED('Exchange Data'[Exchange Currency]),
    "Gross Revenue USD", [Gross Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[ExchangeRate]),
    "Net Revenue USD", [Net Revenue] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[ExchangeRate]),
    "Total Tax USD", [Total Tax] * RELATED('Exchange Data'[ExchangeRate])
)
```

Mine is fine now.